# Consultar base de datos sql

Tags: sql, pgadmin

Necesito consultar en las tablas animal, curado y reporte

- animal contiene: `tipo_de_animal(String)`
- curado contiene: `positivo(bool)`
- reporte contiene: `fecha(date)`

Con sus respectivas llaves que las relacionan.

La idea es contar los tipos de animales presentados por fecha y los que se han curado sin que existan repeticiones de nombres también en esas mismas fechas. Ejemplo

```
animal curado    reporte
vaca    si      2017/06/01
perro   si      2017/06/03
vaca    si      2017/06/01
perro   no      2017/06/03
vaca    no      2017/06/01
```

Quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
animal   cantidad   cantidad_curados    reporte
vaca        3             2             2017/06/01
perro       2             1             2017/06/03
```

Este es mi código

```
select distinct animal.tipo_de_animal as animal
count(*) as cantidad,
(select count(*) from from animal join curado on animal.id =curado.id_animal join reporte 
on curado.id_reporte =reporte.id where reporte.fecha between '20170601' and '20170603')as cantidad_curados,

reporte.fecha as fecha 

from animal join curado on animal.id =curado.id_animal join reporte 
on curado.id_reporte =reporte.id

where 
reporte.fecha between '20170601' and '20170603' 

group by
animal
```

Se que la subconsulta está pésima, ¿me podrían ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Hola suponiendo que las estructuras de las tablas es la siguiente considera utilizar el query que relaciono

Saludos

```
create table test.animal
    (
    id int,
    tipo_de_animal varchar(30)
    );
create table test.curado
    (
    id_animal int,
    id_reporte int,
    positivo varchar(2)
    );
create table test.reporte
    (
    id int,
    fecha varchar(30)
    );

insert into test.animal(id, tipo_de_animal)values(1,"vaca");
insert into test.animal(id, tipo_de_animal)values(2,"perro");

insert into test.reporte(id, fecha)values(1, '2017/06/01');
insert into test.reporte(id, fecha)values(2, '2017/06/03');

insert into test.curado(id_animal, id_reporte, positivo)values(1,1,'si');
insert into test.curado(id_animal, id_reporte, positivo)values(2,2,'si');
insert into test.curado(id_animal, id_reporte, positivo)values(1,1,'si');
insert into test.curado(id_animal, id_reporte, positivo)values(2,2,'no');
insert into test.curado(id_animal, id_reporte, positivo)values(1,1,'no');

WITH cte AS
    (
    SELECT c.id_animal, c.id_reporte, COUNT(*) AS cantidad,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN positivo = 'si' THEN 1
        END) AS cantidad_curados
        FROM test.curado AS c 
        GROUP BY c.id_animal, c.id_reporte
    )
    SELECT 
        a.tipo_de_animal AS animal,
        c.cantidad,
        c.cantidad_curados,
        r.fecha
        FROM cte AS c
        INNER JOIN test.animal AS a
        ON c.id_animal = a.id
        INNER JOIN test.reporte AS r
        ON c.id_reporte = r.id;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta parte del query realizó el COUNT de la "cantidad" y el COUNT condicionado para la "cantidad_curados" con este resultado realizó el join con las demás tablas.

```
WITH cte AS
    (
    SELECT c.id_animal, c.id_reporte, COUNT(*) AS cantidad,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN positivo = 'si' THEN 1
        END) AS cantidad_curados
        FROM test.curado AS c 
        GROUP BY c.id_animal, c.id_reporte
    )
```